# Exchange & split partition have a issue

Tags: oracle12c, database-partitioning

I am trying to exchange non partition data with partition data. I have done following steps.

Created a new table TEMP_TABLE with partition with the TEMP_TABLE_1 range as date('1-09-2019').
And I have used

```
     ALTER TABLE TEMP_TABLE
     EXCHANGE PARTITION TEMP_TABLE_1
     WITH TABLE ORG_TABLE
     WITHOUT VALIDATION
     UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

With this my table data is exchanged with the partition and new table I can see the partition with data.
But now the problem is that the data contains rows with date more than 1-09-2019, when I try

```
     select count(*) from TEMP_TABLE where date > '1-09-2019';
```

its giving 0 though there is data with the date till today.

If I try to split this partition

```
     ALTER TABLE TEMP_TABLE SPLIT PARTITION TEMP_TABLE_1  INTO (PARTITION 
     TEMP_TABLE_2 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2019 00:00:00', 'DD-MON- 
     YYYY HH24:MI:SS')),       PARTITION TEMP_TABLE_1)  UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES 
     PARALLEL 4;
```

Its throwing partition cannot be split along the specified high bound.

How to get the data which is more than the range date i have provided.

Answer (score 0):

As you are exchanging data without validation (probably to improve performance) Oracle won't validate whether the value for partition key column of the data that is inserted matches the partition range condition of the partition into which that data is inserted.

```
--partitioned table
create table mytabp(n date)
partition by range(n)
interval(numtodsinterval(1, 'DAY'))
(partition p0 values less than (to_date('20190901','yyyymmdd')));

--nonpartitioned table to hold the data outside partition range
create table temp_mytab(n date);

insert into temp_mytab values(to_date('20191001','yyyymmdd'));

--exchanging without validation
alter table mytabp exchange partition p0 with table temp_mytab without validation;

--Data exists
select count(1) from mytabp;--1
```

Due to partition pruning in the below query the record is searched in the partition which must hold this data by definition. As the record exists in an incorrect partition that data is not returned.

```
select count(1) from mytabp where n > to_date('20190901','yyyymmdd');--0
```

By applying TRUNC on partitioned column, Oracle is presented with an option to scan all partitions. So the below SQL produces the record. For me on Oracle 12cR1 on Exadata, the subsequent executions of this SQL with TRUNC scanned the exact partition where the record was sitting and did not scan all partitions. I checked this with my explain plan's PARTITON_START and PARTITION_STOP columns.

```
select count(1) from mytabp where trunc(n) > to_date('20190901','yyyymmdd');--1
```

By design it is bad to place data on incorrect partitions. Please validate or filter for the correct data before executing exchange without validation.